# Ionic show menu navigation icon

Tags: ionic2

I am a beginner in Ionic, trying to display a side menu page when users clicks on a button. Instead, what I'm still getting is the back button. Here's my code:

//menu .html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>menu</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

//app.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">



<ion-content padding>

  <h2>This is a cool menu</h2>
  </ion-content>



</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

Ok so, ionic's navigation works like a stack. You push a component on the stack, pop it off or create a new stack.

To push a component on the stack you'll need to call (if you call your `NavController` `navCtrl`) `navCtrl.push(someComponent);`

To pop a component, call `navCtrl.pop(someComponent);`

To create a new stack, call `navCtrl.setRoot(someComponent);`

### Why is this important?

If you want the menu-icon to show, the page has to be at the lowest level of the stack, this is in ionic called the `root`.

When a page is not `root`, the menu-icon will magically transform into a `back-button`, so you can go back to your `root` page. (f.e. when you want to see more details about an item)

### Sure, not really reading anymore, but what do I need to do?

Well, first of all, just include the `<ion-header>` on your page, since you want to show the icon on your page. In your code, you're trying to get a `menu-icon` in your `ion-menu` (which is your sidemenu).

So you will have something like the following, create your menu in `app.component.html`

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-menu type="overlay" [content]="content"> 
  <ion-content>
    <button menuClose icon-only>
      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <button menuClose>
       My Custom button WHOOOOO
    </button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**page1.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Page 1 FTW</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
       // So this icon will change depending on the page's place in the ionic Stack
       <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
         <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>     
       </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
   <button ion-button menuToggle>Open my great menu!</button>
</ion-content>
```

Now in your `app.component.ts` you want to make `Page1` the `root`, this way you'll see your menu icon in the header.

This can easily be done by changing the `rootPage` property of `AppComponent`.

Simply `import { Page1 } from 'your/page1/location'` and call (in constructor f.e. `this.rootPage = Page1;`;

Now `Page1` will have a menu-icon in it's header which will show your menu!

If you want to include a button which opens your menu, just add the `menuToggle` property to it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, what I needed was the setRoot method, instead I was using push

Answer (score 0):

Your tags seems to be in a wrong order. Can you try with code bellow?

```
<ion-menu>

  <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
          <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>

        <h2>This is a cool menu</h2>
    </ion-content>


</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```